# Creating Loc binding in code

Tags: c#, wpflocalizationextension

How can I create a localization binding like `{lex:LocTextUpper XXX}` in code? I have controls that, for reasons of performance, I need to create in code rather than in XAML but I wouldn't like to lose the comfort of automatic string replacement on UI culture change.

Comment: You can do it for example like this `new LocTextUpperExtension("Load").SetBinding(tb, TextBlock.TextProperty);` (where `tb` is some `TextBlock`)

Comment: Thanks, that works very well. It'd deserve an answer. :-)

Comment: Well I have some doubts about that. For example, `LocTextUpperExtension` implements `IDisposable`, but who should dispose it in this case? Not sure